# Access browser print popup for testing purposes

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, e2e-testing

I'm using capybara to write end to end test.

I have a print feature inside my app and would like to access its DOM in order to assert different things on my printed document.

How could I access the popup DOM using Capybara?

+How could I programmatically close the print popup when I'm done asserting? It seems that Capybara is stuck after executing the print method.

[image: popup dom]

ps: I'm using an headless Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This answer only applies to using the Selenium driver with non-deadless chrome, and once you're inside the shadowDOM you can only use CSS selectors which means you can't use any of the Capybara methods that involve Capybaras built-in selectors ('fill_in', 'select', etc). This may also break with any release of Chrome or chromedriver.

Because of the way chromedriver/chrome works, it isn't returning from whatever action you did to open the print window until the print window is closed.  It is technically possible to work around this by triggering the print window asynchronously. But then you run into the issue that most of the print window is inside shadow DOM elements which the WebDriver spec doesn't currently provide an API for. You can however work around that using `evaluate_script`.

Therefore to open and then close a print window would be something like this

```
print_window = page.window_opened_by do
  page.execute_script('window.setTimeout(function(){ window.print();}, 50)')
end

page.within_window(print_window) do
   print_app = page.find('print-preview-app')
   print_app_shadow = print_app.evaluate_script('this.shadowRoot')
   print_header = print_app_shadow.find('print-preview-header')
   print_header_shadow = print_header.evaluate_script('this.shadowRoot')
   print_header_shadow.find('.cancel-button').click
end
```

Obviously all those calls could be chained together, the intermediate elements are only spelled out to make it clearer what is being done.

Comment: It seems to be working in a non headless chrome however not working in headless: `Capybara::WindowError:         Capybara::WindowError: block passed to #window_opened_by opened 0 windows instead of 1` any idea ? @thomas-walpole

Comment: @user2462805 Whoops -- forgot that Chrome disables the print in headless mode (partly because of how it hangs execution).  You'll either have to test this functionality with the browser visible or you could try registering a driver with the `--enable-print-browser` command line switch (displays all pages as if they were being printed) and use that driver for checking what you want to check.

Comment: I'm stuck with a headless Chrome. Could you tell me a bit more about registering a driver? How should I proceed? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @user2462805 To register your own driver see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#configuring-and-adding-drivers and look at what Capybara does for the drivers it registers by default - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L539

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, this answer helped me greatly - Although I'm able to manipulate the print_window, on a mac, there is a system dialog window that pops up after selecting save that confirms where to save the document regardless of defaults. Any idea how to avoid the system dialog window? Have you run into this before? Screenshot here: https://ibb.co/j8Qsjnv